# When is the latest I can complete the Wild Card quests?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Let's say I'm working the various quests in New Vegas, and am currently in the early stages of both [The House Always Wins](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_House_Always_Wins) and the [Wild Card](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_quests#Game_End_Quests) quests.

What is the latest point in The House Always Wins that I can safely complete the Wild Card series, assuming I want to take control New Vegas?

(Note: I do plan on finishing off as many side quests as possible before going this route, so time is not *exactly* a factor here -- I just want to be sure I don't go so far down The House Always Wins that I'm unable to do the Wild Cards.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki you linked reports:

> The final choice on a single faction must be made after the player floats up the B-29 from the lake for the Boomers.

Basically, whomever you tell the Boomers will support you is the faction you'll be locked to for the remainder of the game.

That said, I did tell House I had the Boomers on my side after telling the NCR so, but I told House after the notification 'If you continue helping Mr. House the NCR will no longer accept your help' so I think that that message (or one like it) is your cue.

The exception is Yes Man. None of the quests close if you tell him the Boomers support you (probably because the meetings are a lot more clandestine).

Comment: I'm not sure if that is entirely correct, I've had the NCR quest series remain open after telling Yes Man that the Boomers support me. I've had some quests bugging out at that point, so my experience may not be the intended result.