# When is the last place you can save in Fallout New Vegas to get all endings?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm playing through Fallout New Vegas and I'm aware that there are 4 mutually exclusive endings. I would like to see them all and get all the achievements, but I don't want to play the entire game four times.

Where is the latest point in the game that I can create a checkpoint save that I can go back to in order to get all endings?

Comment: Related: [When is the latest I can complete the Wild Card quests?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/when-is-the-latest-i-can-complete-the-wild-card-quests)

Comment: How much have you played so far?

Comment: @bdap I haven't played very far yet. I'm just leaving Novac. The NCR like me, the Legion are neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've got the Platinum Chip from Benny, then talked to the Yes Man, save before you leave the Tops Casino. Once you leave the Casino your reputation with the Legion and/or the NCR will be set to neutral if you've gained any infamy.

Also, if you really want to save yourself some time you could go to The Boomers and complete most of their quests (just don't go speak to Pearl to finish off the Volaire! quest).

You will have to play through it at least twice though, because the of the Hardcore achievement. (It might also be a good idea to play through with a character with maximum Luck to get The Courier Who Broke The Bank.)

Comment: It is a good idea to explore most of the Mojave before finishing Ring-a-Ding Ding. This way, when you save before leaving The Tops, you will already have a higher level to pursuit the faction-specific quests.
Also, you don't *need* to have a character with max Luck for The Courier Who Broke the Bank, it'll just be easier. I've got that achievement using a character that started with Luck 5 with cautious Blackjacking, Luck Implant and Naughty Nightwear.

Comment: @Wilerson Good points, leveling up will definitely save you time playing through the rest of the endings. I found that playing blackjack on any of my play-throughs was a good way to earn cash regardless of my characters Luck (you'll also get better at real blackjack for when you go to the actual casino :), best odds for sure!)